# Windows Phone 8.1 Right to Left Language support

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am working in a Windows 8.1 Universal (not silverlight) app Windows Phone, and need to support right-to-left languages such as Arabic. Is there a was, other that setting the flow direction on the entire root frame, that I can alight the text right-to left to reflect this language?

Answer (score 0):

You can set FlowDirection for specific Text to "RightToLeft" not for the entire root frame or you can set  HorizontalAlignment to "Right" but this is not a nice way to do it.

Proved your XAML code please ?